# Riemann-Zeta-Like Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Lets consider the sum
$$1-\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}-\frac{1}{7^3}-...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2 i-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$

And as we know there is no known closed form neither for the $\zeta(3)$, nor for the
$$1+\frac{1}{3^3}+\frac{1}{5^3}+\frac{1}{7^3}+...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 i-1)^3}=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}$$

This contrast is really strange, and here just asking to share the thoughts about the possible reason, why the first series is so easy to map to simple relation, while the second one is not.

---

Just an addition:
$$1-\frac{1}{3^5}+\frac{1}{5^5}-\frac{1}{7^5}-...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2 i-1)^5}=\frac{5\pi^5}{1536}$$

$$1-\frac{1}{3^7}+\frac{1}{5^7}-\frac{1}{7^7}-...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{(2 i-1)^7}=\frac{61\pi^7}{184320}$$

and so on.

$$1+\frac{1}{3^5}+\frac{1}{5^5}+\frac{1}{7^5}+...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 i-1)^5}=\frac{31\zeta(5)}{32}$$

$$1+\frac{1}{3^7}+\frac{1}{5^7}+\frac{1}{7^7}+...=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(2 i-1)^7}=\frac{127\zeta(7)}{128}$$

Comment: nice question, I would though argue that $\pi$ is not different from $\zeta(3)$, it the sense that both are not number which you "could write down" :-)

Comment: The real difference is that the $\pi$ is unique, while $\zeta(3), \zeta(5),...$ do not have the common irrational base:)